# Sorting SQL results into categories and displaying them in a table PhP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, categories

I want to display MySQL results like this in a PHP/HTML table. Maybe add mouse over info for each plant if thats easy later.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|category1  ¦ category2 ¦ category3 ¦ category4 ¦ category5 ¦ 
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| plantName ¦ plantName ¦ plantName ¦ plantName ¦ plantName ¦ 
| plantName ¦ plantName ¦ plantName ¦ plantName ¦ plantName ¦ 
| plantName ¦ plantName ¦           ¦           ¦           ¦
|           ¦ plantName ¦           ¦           ¦           ¦
|           ¦ plantName ¦           ¦           ¦           ¦
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

First I select plants by elevation and rainfall values.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `plants_tb` 
WHERE $elevate>= elevationLOW  &&  $elevate<= elevationHI &&
$rainfall>= rainfallLOW  &&  $rainfall<= rainfallHI ORDER BY commonNames ASC");

$plant = 'commonNames';
$elevationH = 'elevationHI';
$elevationL ='elevationLOW';
$rainfallL ='rainfallLOW';
$rainfallH ='rainfallHI';
$species ='species';

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Category</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row[$plant] . "</td><td>" . $row['heightHI'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Now I need to display them in columns by height categories. Maybe I should make a temporary table of the selected plants, then categorize them, then display them in columns?
Here is my idea for categorizing. I know this between code is not correct but, it gets my point out.

```
$sql="SELECT tree_height FROM $Elevation_Rainfall_list;
WHERE tree_height
BETWEEN 1 AND 7 = $Category1
BETWEEN 7 AND 15 = $Category2
BETWEEN 15 AND 30 = $Category3
BETWEEN 30 AND 9999 = $Category4
if not = $Category5
```

mahalo for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to create something like a histogram.

Instead of trying to categorize the data in the SQL query, you should do it in PHP with something like this:

```
$histogram = array();
# classify the data into histogram bins
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $h = $row['tree_height'];
    $cat = 3;
    if ($h <= 7) {
        $cat = 0;
    } elseif ($h <= 15) {
        $cat = 1;
    } elseif ($h <= 30) {
        $cat = 2;
    }
    $histogram[$cat][] = $row['commonNames'];
}

# determine the number of rows in the table
$rows = 0;
foreach ($histogram as $ar) { $rows = max($rows, count($ar)); }

# write a table with the data
echo "<table border='1'>\n" .
     "  <tr>\n    <td>Category 1</td>\n    <td>Category 2</td>\n" .
     "    <td>Category 3</td>\n    <td>Category 4</td>\n</tr>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i) {
    echo "  <tr>\n";
    for ($cat = 0; $cat <= 3; ++$cat) {
        echo "    <td>" . $histogram[$cat][$i] . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "  </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: First mahalo for the input on the project. I am not using your code correctly. I just get a blank page. I was debugging and I found,

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) on line 62`

that would be  `$histogram[$cat][] = $row[$plant];`

maybe this while loop is stuck? 
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))`

Comment: This loop should be OK, because mysql_fetch_array return null (which evaluates to false) when there are no more rows to fetch. It's more likely that your database has a lot of records and you need more memory to process them all. How many rows are there in your result? Put 'echo mysql_num_rows($sql)' somewhere after your query to find out.

Comment: There are 52 rows and 10 columns. echo mysql_num_rows($sql) returns 30. Looks like its the "for" loop in the HTML table? Or the formating of the echos? $histogram is holding results its just not displaying.

Comment: I get a results from this
`echo "<table border='1'>\n" .
     "  <tr>\n    <td>Category 1</td>\n    <td>Category 2</td>\n" .
     "    <td>Category 3</td>\n    <td>Category 4</td>\n</tr>\n";

echo "   <tr>\n <td>" . $histogram[$cat][1] . "</td>\n <td>" . $histogram[$cat][2] . "</td>\n
<td>" . $histogram[$cat][3] . "</td>\n <td>" . $histogram[$cat][4] . "</td>\n</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";`

Comment: Category 1 ¦ Category 2 ¦ Category 3 ¦ Category 4 ¦

Papaya  ¦ Lime ¦ Lemon ¦  Mulberry ¦

Comment: Your echo line is definitely wrong, since it outputs a table row with the second, third, fourth and fifth plant in the first category. This is definitely not what you want.

Comment: I noticed there was a typo - instead of `for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++i) {` it should have been `for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i) {`.

Comment: awesome! thank you . it works kind of. results show properly in the table but also get this error.
Notice: Undefined offset: 3  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 4  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 5  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 6  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 7  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 8  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 9  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 10  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 11  on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 12  on line 76

Comment: ok nevermind looks like its getting all the results displayed. Mahalo nui loa for your support.

Comment: this is a gifting community project to help people grow healty food and build sustainable backyard enviroments in Hawaii. there is more work to be done on this project. if you would like to continue your support in tis same capacity or grater please let me know. you are welcomed in Hawaii. Hope to meet you on the beach some day.